# JavaScript based Bookmark button that fetches images

Tags: javascript

I saw bookmark button on http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ which list all big images or videos on the page.

I checked out the source code and found out that the bookmark button consist of JavaScripts.

What is the term that describes this functionality?

Is there any documentation or good tutorial that explains creating that kind of bookmark button?

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I can't point you to any tutorials, but it works more or less by creating a JavaScript function and making a hyperlink whose href is `javascript:(function(){yourCode();})`